# Why does append return none

Tags: python

```
def num(x=[], y=[],result=[]):
    x.append(120), y.append(0)
    result.append(print("Progress"))
    x.append(0), y.append(120)
    result.append(print("Exclude"))
    print(len(result))
    print(result)
    num()
```

Comment: format your code in your question

Answer (score 2):

print is build_in function and after call the function it print its argument and return None.So when you append print("Progress") to a list actually you append None to list.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a return statement to the function:

```
return (x, y, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping **print** function:

```
def num(x=[], y=[],result=[]): 
    x.append(120) 
    y.append(0) 
    result.append("Progress")
    x.append(0)
    y.append(120)
    result.append("Exclude") 
    print(len(result)) 
    print(result) 
num()
```